# Error: Permission denied to access property "Value_Object"

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net

I am trying to load a asp.net application url inside a php iframe. When I am trying to run the php application, I am getting the below error

Error: Permission denied to access property "Value_Object"  webpage.aspx (line 500, col 1)

Could you please help me in this to fix the issue

```
     function prepareFrame() {
     var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
     ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://iisserver/aspnet/WebPage.aspx");
     ifrm.style.width = "640px";
     ifrm.style.height = "480px";
     document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
     }
     prepareFrame();
```

It's not showing any error in the php application, It's showing error in the asp.net file.

Comment: Would be nice to see the code you're referring to...

Comment: Add it to your question with proper formatting...

Comment: loading the iframe using javascript in php

Comment: formatted the code in the question

Comment: You need to include the code that's actually failing.